# How to load custom sql functions with django

Tags: django, postgresql

I am trying to use Django's initial SQL data functionality to create an SQL function. The docs state I can do this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-sql-data

> Django provides a hook for passing the database arbitrary SQL that’s executed just after the CREATE TABLE statements when you run migrate. You can use this hook to populate default records, or you could also create SQL functions, views, triggers, etc.

After some googling I found that django's customsql code splits any sql files and runs them line by line, creating this error,

> Failed to install custom SQL for myapp.somemodel model: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$ BEGIN;"

Is there an accepted work around for this? Or a better way to load custom sql functions?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I've seen this problem before. If you stick a multi-line function in your app's sql/<modelname>.sql like so:

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION increment(i integer) RETURNS integer AS $$
        BEGIN
                RETURN i + 1;
        END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;`

you'll get the error you saw, namely something like:

> Failed to install custom SQL for mysite.Poll model: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$ BEGIN RETURN i + 1;"
>   LINE 1: ... FUNCTION increment(i integer) RETURNS integer AS $$ BEGIN R...

I think you should be able to work around the problem by squeezing the function definition all onto one line, e.g.

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION increment(i integer) RETURNS integer AS $$BEGIN RETURN i + 1; END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;`

Looks like this bug affects any multi-line functions (both dollar-quoted and single-quoted). I tested on Django 1.6, no idea if it's been fixed already.